# Out of range exception on GetElementsByName and GetElementsByTagName

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, so usually I dont need help when it comes to debugging but this has me very puzzled. So essentially I am trying to create a program that automatically logs me into the network system used at my complex.

I am achieving this through a web browser component. Ok now lets talk code.

This is the function.

```
private void Login(Dictionary<string, string> credentials)
    {
        // This can cause errors
        //HtmlElement LoginForm = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[0];

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in credentials)
        {
            // This is the exception call point
            webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName(param.Key)[0].SetAttribute("value", param.Value);
        }

        webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("login")[0].InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

And this is the credentials it is using for the foreach

```
Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"UserName", "******"},
        {"Password", "******"},
    };
```

Now the error seems to be:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
Parameter name: index'

Now what makes this even more annoying and weirder is that the foreach statement is successful in filling the form! [How ridiculous!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdC8.png) I've found that this error happens on basically every single tag that I use it on.

I'm super confused

Comment: If 0 is not valid, the Colleciton is Empty. Simple as that.

Comment: As for the specific Exception Message, it is telling you the "'Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and [Count]". In order to identify that value has not yet been set, they are set to invalid values. A special "None" or "Invalid" for Enumerations. -1 for Integers that should be only above 0 like Count/Size/Lenght values.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but did you read any of the code @Christopher ??? The foreach statement fills the form boxes even though the index's for the items are null??????

Comment: You would have to have made some serious mistakes in your Exception handling for this to even be *possible*. Exceptions end the Execution of the code. And Index Out of Range Exceptions belong to the kind that should only ever be fixed, never caught (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). But as there is no Try/Catch anywhere in the shown code, I can only asume this is not your real code and/or not the code actually throwing the Exception.

Comment: @Offnix What are you using, is it WPF or WinForms? Which line of code causes an error?